# How HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() is buld?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to train a SVM using openCV and I've succeded. I want to set this trained SVM insted of the default one to detect persons with the hog.detectMultiScale() method, but the size doesent match. My quetion is : how the HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector() is builded and is there any possibuility in Python to build a compatible SVM and use it instead of the default one?